# How to set constraint on nn.Parameter in Pytorch？

Tags: python, pytorch

I defined an updatable matrix in the initialization of the network, for example:

```
def __init__():       
    self.pattern= nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1,1,256,256))
```

I want to limit `self.pattern` values to 0 and 1, and try to make them as close to 0 and 1 as possible after training, or relatively evenly distributed between 0 and 1. What should I do?

I added `torch.sigmoid(self.pattern)` in `def forward()`, but the `self.pattern` variable was trained between 0.7 and 1.9, and even after sigmoid, the minimum value was still large. So when I show `self.pattern` as an image, it's very dark.

Thank you for your attention! I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Please kindly show the `def forward()` block as there's something wrong on your try.

Comment: Actually, the initial value of "self.pattern" I defined was a number between 0 and 1, so my forward function performed some operations on the sigmoid to ensure that their values were as close to 0 and 1 as possible, as follows:  pattern1=F.sigmoid((self.pattern-0.5)*10)

Comment: Why dont you just normalize it between 0 and 1 at the end before plotting the image?

Comment: I've tried this before, but using MinMax to regularize between 0 and 1 is the same as drawing without regularization.